# Devise Sign Out Error - The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Devise generated the following code to sign a user out:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path %>
```

And the route appears when executing `rake routes`

```
destroy_user_session DELETE     /users/sign_out(.:format)
{:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
```

However I'm getting an error saying:

```
The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

the path is correct but if you look closely you see that it's not a GET request but a DELETE request so pass the method:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

Edit:

This should add a `data-method="delete"` attribute to your link. Verify that (have a look at the generated HTML). If the attribute is present and nothing happens if you click on that link, then ensure that you've included the default javascript files in your layout. There should be a line like:

`<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>`

in your layout.

**>>Important<<**: You can't type the logout url into your address bar and hit enter, it won't work because it's a GET and not a DELETE request. The magic behind this is that a javascript helper will hook on to the "onclick" event of the link and then submit a hidden form (via POST) to the `href` destination of the url containing a hidden field called `_method` with the value "delete".

Why all this? It's a security thing, otherwise someone could redirect you to the logout page and simply log you out and all your unsaved session stuff will be gone...

If you reeeeaaaallllyyy need a logout via GET then add this to your

**config/initializers/devise.rb**:

`config.sign_out_via = :get`

Comment: I've tried that adding that and unfortunately still am seeing the same error. Any other ideas? http://cl.ly/3h1T3n1k3h1D2c270u2H

Comment: Thanks for that, however it still doesn't work :( There is a `data-methid="delete"` attribute on that link, and the default javascript files were included in the layout. Any other ideas?

Comment: open up the rails server console and watch what happens if you click on logout: Is there a line like `Started DELETE "/users/sign_out"` ?

Comment: nope, nothing along those lines. This is produced instead `AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController)`

Comment: interesting - actually it should take you to the `SessionsController` is there another route which points to /users/sign_out ? (Important: Is /users/sign_out called via GET or DELETE? - just to make sure its not a client-side/javascript problem)

Comment: There aren't any other routes pointing to /user/sign_out. Interestingly it looks like it's being called via a GET instead of a DELETE (according to Chrome's dev tools http://cl.ly/2H360B0J3U2z433r1Y2T)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4708/discussion-between-sled-and-elliot)

Comment: This post might help: http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2011-12-11-devise-actioncontroller-routingerror-no-route-matches-get-slash-users-slash-sign-out

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that you have required jquery in your application.js as '//= require jquery'. Put it on top of '//= require jquery_ujs' in the application.js. Afterwards restart the server.